# Naming computer after install

Tags: setup

I'm having a hard time even searching for the topic. I'm trying to install Lubuntu on an old PC I have. What I would like to do is install the OS, but leave the name and password empty. I'm going to be giving this PC away, and I would like to have the recipient turn on the pc and have it ask them to create a name and a password. This is basically what Windows does when you buy it new, right?

Is there a way to make this happen in L/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go on reading about the [OEM Installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview).

Comment: Wow, that totally answers the question. Thanks!